# Derivation for the skin depth of a wire given RF signal

Tags: rf

I was looking at the equation for the resistance of a wire under RF signal and failed to produce similar results.

On WikiPedia article on [skin effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) this resistance is given by:

$$R = \frac{\rho L}{\pi D \delta}$$

Can anyone please explain how the bottom corresponds to the area of the wire?

Recall that for a wire under DC current we have:

$$R = \frac{\rho L}{A}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom does not correspond to the area of the wire. That's the whole idea behind skin effect -- the current is confined to a region near the surface of the wire, so the bottom of the equation is proportional to the *circumference* of the wire (πD).